# Android camera2 createCaptureRequest returns all black pixels when getting YUV_420_888 image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a Android camera2 API **preview** running ok in Kotlin using suspendCoroutine for all the surface setup and callbacks.  But when I try to take a picture 5 seconds after the app starts (TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE, YUV_420_888, smallest res) for some reason it all goes completely black for a moment (even in the preview window) and I get a YUV image full of 0-lum pixels.

```
private suspend fun captureStill(): Image = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    val captureRequestStill = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)
    captureRequestStill.addTarget(imageReaderYUV.surface)
    imageReaderYUV.setOnImageAvailableListener({ cont.resume(imageReaderYUV.acquireLatestImage()) }, backgroundHandler)
    cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureRequestStill.build(), null, backgroundHandler)
}
```

Am I missing something?  Did I mangle some aspect of the setup earlier?  Is setOnImageAvailableListener not ok for capturing a YUV image?

[See the full setup dance in one suspend-enabled function](https://github.com/salamanders/MotionCamera/blob/6e561e85f24cccfa3d75dd7bd85b01e3d2ef830b/app/src/main/java/info/benjaminhill/motioncamera/MainActivity.kt#L59)

Comment: Which size do you get in the end? One problem with your setup is that you change the requested resolution, which *may* require full reset of the camera capture path. The best approach would be to choose the same resolution for preview and YUV capture.

Comment: @AlexCohn good question! I *think* there is only the one place where I set a res: imageSizeForYUVImageReader.  Checking... AUGH.  I had set the TextureView layout_width in DP!!  Changing it to px works!  (but now I'm all worried about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307191/how-to-set-android-camera2-preview-and-capture-size given that I'm using TextureView instead of SurfaceView, and having a layout res break everything is sketching me out... but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

While setting up your Camera preview, you implicitly chose some preview size. Generally speaking, your capture can use different size (even to YUV, which is essentially preview buffer, too).

But on many devices, uncoordinated choice of preview and capture sizes does not work well. The common phenomenon is that you must select preview size and Jpeg capture size to have same aspect ratio. I strongly recommend you to follow this practice for YUV, too.

You can use [SurfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#setDefaultBufferSize(int,%20int)) if you want to keep the TextureView size fit the general layout.

Comment: I'm not using SurfaceTexture anywhere AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, you [are](https://github.com/salamanders/MotionCamera/blob/6e561e85f24cccfa3d75dd7bd85b01e3d2ef830b/app/src/main/java/info/benjaminhill/motioncamera/MainActivity.kt#L75)

Comment: Oh.  OH.  Yes, I am! My bad, thank you!  But, the setDefaultBufferSize docs say "Both video and camera based image producers do override the size" so I wasn't setting anything there explicitly, instead taking it from the TextureView android:layout_width (in pixels) which seems like a very fragile thing to do.

Comment: Yes, this whole setup is rather fragile. I think that the "clean" approach would be to establish your capture request eagerly enough (before live preview starts), and only trigger it ON when the necessary. Alas, I cannot prove this right now in actual try running code sample.